# How to make orgmode decorate quotes?

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

Org mode decorates some parts of text (like section headers with yellow), but I'd like to add other ones such as double quotes (such as strings when I am editing Lisp code).

Comment: See the Elisp manual doc for info about `font-lock`. When asking for help with this, you might want to specify what kind of quoting you mean: single quote of a Lisp sexp? Double-quoted text (string)?

Comment: I guess in theory, you could customize the variable `org-emphasis-alist` for this. However, in practice there seems to be a bug, or at least it does not work here. I have tried to set as marker `'`, `"` and `^` to `org-quote` and `org-code` face (types found in org-faces.el), and reloaded org as instructed in the docstring. However, it has no effect. Still I think it is appropriate to mention the 'theory' case here. Maybe you can try, and if it does not work we could open a bug report.

Comment: @dalanicolai That's exactly what I wanted to do. But it has no effect for me too. Tried single and double quotes, different values (org-quote, org-code, org-verbatim) and none of them work.